# Warning: comparison b/w pointer and integer in C.

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    char name[10], food[10], color[10], ans[10];
    int height, year, age, date; 

    /* Ask for user inputs and do stuff here */
    /* ------------------------------------- */

    printf("Would you like me to repeat this?\n");
    scanf("%c", ans);   

    /* its giving me a warning for the if condition on the line  */ 
    /* below saying warning: comparison b/w pointer and integer. */

    if  (ans == 'y')
        printf("ok I will\n");
    else
        printf("fine.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

At the end of the program, I wrote an IF statement where if user types "y" then it'll say "ok I will" ELSE say "fine" -nothing fancy.
But when I run it, the program would ask me "Would you like me to repeat this?" and even though I type "y" the program will output "fine" instead of "ok I will"... please help.

Comment: The warning is there for a reason

Comment: You couldn't be bothered to write out "between" in full?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `ans` is an array, and can decay to a pointer to the first element. You compare it to a character.

You should change to e.g. `ans[0] == 'y'`.

Or even better, since you only read a single character, why us an array at all? Just declare `ans` as a single character, and use the address-of operator in the `scanf` call:

```
char ans;

scanf(" %c", &ans);

if (tolower(ans) == 'y') ...
```

Comment: there is the probability that a newline is still in the input stream when the scanf() is called. so the call to scanf() fails.  then ans contains what ever trash is on the stack at the location where 'ans' exists.  The suggestion to use a leading space in the format string will fix that.  However, checking the returned value from scanf() would have caught that problem.  Yet another very good reason to make a habit of checking the returned values from calls to system functions.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to the following and it works: `char ans` and `if (ans == 'y')`... Can you clarify why you used 'tolower' in your example? Also, can you explain the purpose of the space in `" %c"` a little clearer? @joachim

Comment: Additionally, what if i wanted to scanf for the word "yes" instead of 'y'? I tried: `char ans[4];` with `scanf (" %s", &ans);` and `if (ans == "yes")`. However, It only outputs "fine" instead of "ok, I will". Sorry if these questions are really basic... I'm a noob (obviously).

Thanks for all you guys' help so far.

Comment: @Vince You can't use `==` to compare arrays or pointer, as that will indeed compare the pointers and not the contents of what the pointers actually point to. To compare strings you need to use the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing ans which is regarded as pointer ,to 'y' which is regarded as integer. change char ans[10] to char ans.